# Стоит ли ставить Anaconda на Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

Как уживаются предустановленные python2 и python3 в убунте с идущими в дистрибутиве анаконды? Могут ли возникнуть какие-то проблемы? Или лучше ставить необходимые библиотеки по отдельности без использования анаконды?

Какие вообще могут быть последствия от повторной установки уже существующих компонентов, одинаковой версии или разных версий. Встанут рядом? Перезапишут друг друга? Вообще перестанут работать? Или каждая библиотека по разному может отреагировать?

Хочется с самого начала разобраться, как это работает, чтобы потом дни напролет не исправлять все косяки.

Comment: Чтобы точно не столкнуться с проблемами, используйте вируальные окружения.

Comment: можно поставить локально для одного пользователя, не трогая предустановленные ...

Comment: у неё вроде свой виртуаленв

Comment: Я ставил и проблем не заметил. Anaconda ставится отдельно, интерпретатор для запуска своего проекта вы выбираете сами.

Comment: @mkkik то есть внутрь virtualenv ставить анаконду?

Comment: @dnlv, да, можно. Но выше сказали, что она и так отдельно ставится.